# input nested inside print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

Fairly simple question here. I was working on constructing an example of the hello world program which would say hello to a user upon input of their name without using any variables. I have

```
print('What is your name?')

print('Hello, ' +str(input()) + ', nice to meet you!')
```

which gives the desired result. Why does the input statement execute ''before'' the print statement despite being nested inside of it? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that being nested inside would mean it would execute later?  What would you expect the `print` to print if the `input` had not yet executed?

Comment: Because, as with math, things inside of brackets are evaluated before things outside of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you are not aware of precedence of operators. Here you are using + operator.

```
print('Hello, ' +str(input()) + ', nice to meet you!')
```

Here, different operand expressions are made ready, before print is executed. Since str(input()) is a function expression, it must be evaluated first, for the string concatenation to take place.

In other scenarios, such as factorial(sum(2, 3)) will result into factorial(5), as sum(2, 3) will be executed first. 
In short, the rule of thumb is that inner most expressions are evaluated first from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

```
3 * (2 + 2)
```

What do expect the answer would be? It's 12, since the part inside the brackets is evaluated first.

It's the same in programming. Things outside of brackets are dependant on things inside brackets, so things inside brackets are evaluated first.